# Not receiving mqtt message on mobile web-client via paho mqttws31.js

Tags: javascript, web-applications, retain, mqtt, paho

I use paho mqttws31.js (http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) for receiving mqtt messages via websockets in a web-app. On pcs with different browsers(chromeium, firefox ...) everything works totally smooth without any errors. But when I use exactly the same source-code on mobile devices, like tablets or smartphones I don't receive retained messages. I subscribe for some retained topic inside of the onSuccess callback when I connect to the broker. But I don't receive the retained message most of the time.
As mentioned this only happens on mobile devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176643/android-paho-mqtt-client-does-not-receive-messages-once-network-connectivity-c

Comment: no this refers to java and not javascript(big difference) + as mentioned twice it works in non-mobile browsers.

Comment: I've had a look on mosquitto and noticed, that as soon as the webclient subscribes the retained topic the retained message is sent: 1410481320: Sending PUBLISH to clientId-NCrfWsdfTwn (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'current_topics', ... (3144 bytes)) But this message never manages to get to the mobile device.

Comment: What broker / websockets and versions are you using?

Comment: Mosquitto 1.3.1 in conjunction with lighttpd for websocketsupport.

Comment: I just cannot understand why it works totally fine on non-mobile devices, so I guess it must be an issue of mobile browsers?

Comment: I have seen something similar before, are you able to download the broker/websockets from hivemq.com and see if that works fine with your setup?

Comment: With the hive broker it seems to work.

Comment: I had a similar problem with mosquitto and lighttp. Never got around to solving it, just used hivemq. Mosquitto 1.4 (yet to be released), you can compile it and it has built in websockets.

Comment: Thanks i already came upon this solution, but somehow i cannot start the broker with websockets:1410648873: mosquitto version 1.4 (build date 2014-09-12 15:45:30+0200) starting
1410648873: Config loaded from websocket.conf.
1410648873: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1410648873: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1410648873: Error: Unable to create websockets listener on port 8010.

Comment: Have you got anything else running on that port 8010? ```netstat -anltp|grep :8010```

Comment: No I don't have anything else running. If I execute the command with sudo I receive: Error: Invalid user 'mosquitto'

Comment: This has to be a bug with lighttpd+websockets in my opinion. What version of both of those are you using?

Comment: Oh, and try the latest 1.4 branch - you may have fallen foul of https://bugs.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+bug/1370111

Comment: I defined the http_dir within the config, but nevertheless receive the same error.

Comment: I'm still getting this issue now in 2023 - all fine on pc but not working correctly on mobile browsers. Was this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

So for the ones who don't want to read all of the comments.
This is seems to be a bug of mosquitto in conjunction with lighttpd, as websocket-provider.

What you can do:

either use:
(simple way) HiveMQ(http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-over-websockets-with-hivemq/) it supports websockets inherently, so the installation is a breeze, but it's not opensource and as it is written in Java I'm not sure if it is as fast as mosquitto, but I definitely don't know.

or: invest some time in compiling the newest version(1.4) of mosquitto, which also supports websockets natively: http://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/ (but is not released so far) this version also seems to fix this problem. Installing newest mosquitto: http://goochgooch.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/

Edit0: I checked the speed and must say HiveMQ with websockets is way faster than mosquitto with websockets. I already noticed it when I connected via websockets, because there was a small latency. Then I sent 1000 values to the browser where they were returned to the subscribing client again. Hive seems to be 3-times faster than mosquitto (I have to commit that this may not be a reliable experiment). So for me my decision is obvious, as long as mosquitto doesn't work properly along with lighttpd-websocket support I will stay with hive. Would be nice to hear some opinions.

Edit1: I'm in a dilemma: Websocketsupport through lighttpd is very fast, way faster than the new mosquitto websocket support and faster than hivemq. As I am running the mqtt-broker on a raspberry, I'm dependent on good performance so neither of the discussed solutions of Edit0 is appropriate for me. But if I use lighttpd I face the originally described problem.

Does somebody have a more convenient solution?

Thx for your help.

Comment: As I said above, I'm sure this is a bug in lighttpd+mod_websockets. What version of both of them are you using?

Comment: Also, could you give more details on how you measured the speed?

Comment: I am using lighttpd 1.4 with mod_websocket 3.5 is this a wrong combination? If so could you tell me which versions fit together? I measure the speed by the round trip time measured through a python script. It sends arbitrary 256 bytes to a subscribing web-client via a mosquitto broker on the raspberry pi. The web-client sends the packets immediately back to the other client.

Comment: Can anyone suggest another solution?

Comment: regarding the mosquitto websocket performance, it's an known issue in the polling loop of mosquitto. see issue 147 https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/147. you can wait till Roger release 1.6 with a new event loop. or add the libwebsocket fd to the `WSAPoll()`'s fdlist or modify its timeout default value of 100ms to something like 30ms or 10ms. if your test showed 3x difference between mosquitto and hive, it's quite possible they are close today or soon.